# api-gateway - http proxy - add sigv4 security to specific resources

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, express, proxy, amazon-iam

In the following swagger file I have defined an api for `aws api-gateway`. The api has been secured using IAM, so that only authorised users can access it. The api also uses the http-proxy definition so that it can sit in front of an `express` app and I don't have to define each resource individually in the swagger file. This way I can develop my express app as I would if not running on aws and then simply port it to aws ([tutorial on how to](https://medium.com/@hyprstack/porting-expressjs-apis-onto-aws-api-gateway-12161c8c0635#.wvk6dofx1))! However, I now need to allow access to all `GET` methods to be unsecured and only have the `sigv4` security definition on all the other methods.
Is this possible with the current set-up of `api-gateway` + `express`?

```
---
swagger: 2.0
info:
  title: ServerlessExpress
basePath: /internal
schemes:
- https
paths:
  /:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
        uri: <my uri>
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    options:
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS,POST'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
  /{proxy+}:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: proxy
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
      responses: {}
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: <my uri>
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    options:
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS,POST'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
securityDefinitions:
  sigv4:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "Authorization"
    in: "header"
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "awsSigv4"
definitions:
  Empty:
    type: object
    title: Empty Schema
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have decided to answer my own question here! It's way simpler than I had thought it would be... however the swagger definition is a little repetitive, it saves time later when developing new resources in the api.

```
---
swagger: 2.0
info:
  title: YOUR_API_GATEWAY_NAME
basePath: /YOUR_API_GATEWAY_STAGE
schemes:
- https
paths:
  /:
    get:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
        uri: <my uri>
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    post:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
        uri: <my uri>
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    patch:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
        uri: <my uri>
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    put:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
        uri: <my uri>
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    delete:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
        uri: <my uri>
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    options:
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,DELETE,PUT,PATCH'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Link,Total-Count,X-XX-Cereberus-Auth,Client-Origin'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
  /{proxy+}:
    get:
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: proxy
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
      responses: {}
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: <my uri>
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    post:
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: proxy
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
      responses: {}
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: <my uri>
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    put:
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: proxy
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
      responses: {}
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: <my uri>
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    patch:
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: proxy
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
      responses: {}
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: <my uri>
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    delete:
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: proxy
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
      responses: {}
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: <my uri>
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    options:
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,DELETE,PUT,PATCH'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Link,Total-Count,X-XX-Cereberus-Auth,Client-Origin'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
securityDefinitions:
  sigv4:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "Authorization"
    in: "header"
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "awsSigv4"
definitions:
  Empty:
    type: object
    title: Empty Schema
```